# Cassandra AssertionError

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

I received an OOM exception at one point in Cassandra. Mine is a single instance running on a modestly powered server, and i was doing some load testing, so no surprise there.

But, i have subsequently been unable to use the instance. When i list the keyspaces, only "system" is shown. But when i try to recreate the keyspace i was testing with, Hector responds with the dreaded "All host pools marked down. Retry burden pushed out to client." message, and the Cassandra log has the following stack trace:

```
ERROR [MigrationStage:1] 2012-04-27 20:47:00,863 AbstractCassandraDaemon.java (line 134) Exception in thread Thread[MigrationStage:1,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTable.updateKeyspace(DefsTable.java:441)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTable.mergeKeyspaces(DefsTable.java:339)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTable.mergeSchema(DefsTable.java:269)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationManager$1.call(MigrationManager.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
ERROR [Thrift:9] 2012-04-27 20:47:00,864 CustomTThreadPoolServer.java (line 204) Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFuture(FBUtilities.java:372)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationManager.announce(MigrationManager.java:191)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationManager.announceNewKeyspace(MigrationManager.java:129)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraServer.system_add_keyspace(CassandraServer.java:987)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$system_add_keyspace.getResult(Cassandra.java:3370)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Processor$system_add_keyspace.getResult(Cassandra.java:3358)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:32)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:34)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AssertionError
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFuture(FBUtilities.java:368)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTable.updateKeyspace(DefsTable.java:441)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTable.mergeKeyspaces(DefsTable.java:339)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTable.mergeSchema(DefsTable.java:269)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationManager$1.call(MigrationManager.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    ... 3 more
```

The old keyspace was still in the data dir, so i moved it, but that didn't help. It seems that the system data still has an invalid reference somewhere. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit: from the CLI, a "describe cluster;" only describes the "system" keyspace. But when i "use system;" and then "list schema_keyspaces;" the following is displayed:

```
Using default limit of 100
-------------------
RowKey: mango
=> (column=durable_writes, value=true, timestamp=29127788177516974)
=> (column=name, value=mango, timestamp=29127788177516974)
=> (column=strategy_class, value=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy, timestamp=29127788177516974)
=> (column=strategy_options, value={"replication_factor":"1"}, timestamp=29127788177516974)

1 Row Returned.
Elapsed time: 1107 msec(s).
```

"mango" is the keyspace that i can no longer access, but it is still in there to some degree. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I ended up just deleting everything in commitlog, data, and saved_caches and restarting. So, bottom line is that i was not able to recover the keyspace without ditching everything else in the cluster. As such, both answers are correct. I marked samarth's as such because he provided a bit more information that may be useful in other situations.

Comment: Are you doing all the operations from cassandra-cli? can you mention steps to recreate this issue so that we can try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is due to inconsistency and you can go for following steps.

1) In your case this is OK to clear "data" , "saved_caches" and "commitlog" directories as you dont have any critical data and other Keyspaces.

2) In the scenarios where you have some critical data and you can not delete above mentioned directories do the following.

- Use **nodetool drain** to Empty the commitlog on all the nodes of the cluster.
- Then delete all the **"LocationInfo*"** files from "/data/system" directories and restart the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info about nodetool. I do now have other keyspaces that i'm not eager to delete, so i did option 2). However, the same problem persists. See my note to dtootill above for more info. When i list keyspaces, it is not there. A command to create it completes successfully, but when i try to use it, i get "why:Keyspace mango does not exist".

Comment: First of all stop cassandra cluster.Try deleting "LocationInfo*" files from all the nodes. Also delete directory from the data folder which is having same name as your keyspace.restart cluster , recreate keyspace and check the permissions of directories in data directory.

Comment: Still the same result: not listed in keyspaces, i'm allowed to create, but when i try to use i get errors. Is there a way to fix the schema_keyspaces files? Is see "mango" showing up in them.

Answer (score 2):

The problem almost certainly is that the recreated keyspace is inconsistent with the commit log or data stored with the original definition.  Shut down the Cassandra server and clear out the commitlog, saved_caches, and data directory corresponding to the keyspace.  The locations of these directories are in cassandra.yaml - look for data_file_directories, saved_caches_directory, and commitlog_directory.

Comment: Thanks dtootill. The commitlog dir doesn't contain files that are specific to the errant keyspace. I did delete other stuff, but when i restarted the problem persisted. I also noted that the name of the keyspace shows up in the Data.db file in the system/schema_keyspaces dir. I believe this is part of the problem, no?

Comment: Thanks Thanks dtootill. It helps solving my problem too.